# VW Polo - new suspension arm clunk

Tags: suspension

I had new front suspension arms fitted on my 06 Polo today. Now there’s clunking on one side when I go over dips in the road or when braking. I’m thinking maybe the brake is loose or something?

Cheers

Comment: Take it back to whoever did the repairs, they left something loose.

Comment: Had the same on a Landrover, loud clunks turned out to be a loose track rod? as said by @moab take it back to the repairer

Comment: Going to have to. Problem is I’m on the other side of the country at the moment and have to drive back 

Answer (score 0):

More information on your car would be helpful.  Such as mileage.

Here are the places which are a high probability for the clunk you describe:

- strut bearing/bushing area looseness and wear
- sway bar bushing (I don't know if the Polo has a sway bar)
- bushings on control arm
- linkages, such as sway bar linkages

The noise is not likely a loose brake caliper, but that should be easy enough to inspect with the wheel off.  It's not a reliable indicator, but the clunk when braking kind of tilts the probability to the control arm bushings.

Comment: Hi, mileage is 136,000. There’s was no noise prior to the arms being replaced. Both were minors on my last mot in June. Don’t know about sway bars, but there’s is an ‘anti roll bar linkage’ which appears to be a bar that attaches at one end to the shock absorber (I only know this because I can see where a new one was fitted last year. Thank you

Comment: Sway and roll bar are the same.   Given mileage, I would suspect the top of the struts.

Comment: I’m with Mongo on this one. Top of strut is just a bit loose. Half a turn loose on top nut generates loud impact noise. Easy fix. Three minutes max.

Comment: Thank you. Having watched a fitting video last night that seems to be the only possibility - was thinking maybe they’ve not put any pressure underneath when tightening the nut?

Comment: Having jacked it up and checked the nuts they seem okay. Leaves the bush as the only culprit, would have thought they’d have checked it when they fitted the arm, so i’ll have to take it back in